# Double each occurrence of a char recursively

Tags: java, recursion

The exercise is to write a recursive method that takes a `String` and a `char` parameter and returns a `String` with each occurrence of the `char` doubled. Additionally, the number of doubling operations should be added at the end of the string. No "extern" variables outside the method are allowed to use. The `String` parameter can contain any valid `char`, including numbers.

My code works up to 1000 doubling operations, but not correctly for 1001. My question is whether this is just a rounding error or whether this task is theoretical unsolvable.

```java
public class Doubly {
    public static String doubly(final String s, final char c) {
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            if (c == s.charAt(0)) {
                int len1 = s.length();
                String s1 = "" + c + c + doubly(s.substring(1), c);
                int len2 = s1.length();
                int lenDiff = len2 - len1;
                int log = (int) Math.log10(lenDiff - Math.log(lenDiff + 1) + 1) + 1;
                if (log > 0) {
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(s1.length() - log));
                    return s1.substring(0, s1.length() - log) + (n + 1);
                }
                return s1;
            }
            return "" + s.charAt(0) + doubly(s.substring(1), c);
        }
        return "0";
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String s = "ccc";
        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
            s += "a";
            String s2 = doubly(s, 'a');
            System.out.println("Expected: " + (i + 1) + ", actual: " + s2.substring(s2.length() - (int) Math.log10(i + 1) - 1));
            if (!String.valueOf(i + 1)
                    .equals(s2.substring(s2.length() - (int) Math.log10(i + 1) - 1))) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## typo

Wow, you *really* like that
[log10](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/jdk.incubator.vector/jdk/incubator/vector/VectorOperators.html#LOG10)
expression. I see several occurrences of it.
Might be worth packaging up in a helper function.
Which you could [unit test](https://junit.org/junit5).

I don't understand this expression at all:

```
    int log = (int) Math.log10(lenDiff - Math.log(lenDiff + 1) + 1) + 1;
```

You *say* the code works correctly,
but how is natural log relevant?
Or is that just a typo bug?

Recall that examining length of `Integer.toString(n)` is another way
to learn its base-ten logarithm.
(My initial theory was the bug was due to FP rounding issues,
until I saw natural log working its way into the mix.
Or perhaps a string length [OBOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) related to 99 -> 100 or 999 -> 1000.)

## recursive function that iterates

You embrace recursion fully with this test:

```
            if (c == s.charAt(0)) {
```

So the (non-empty) base case is a test for: "Starts with `c`?"

Another approach would have been to examine
s[.indexOf(c)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)),
which iterates until hitting either a match or end-of-string.
A `-1` says there's no more recursing to do.
Else we turn a "FRONT c BACK" string into "FRONT cc BACK".

## data format

You're passing around "ccccNN", along with an integer, the string length.
And you're finding it a bit of a challenge both to get that format right,
and to debug it when things go south.
Recommend you adopt a simpler format.

At the outset you might try sample delimiters, such as SPACE or ↑ or 气,
till you find one that is not present in `s`.
Pass it around as a parameter during recursive calls.
Then your format is "cccc NN", and `s.reverseIndexOf(' ')`
lets you split apart string from the serialized count.
Hmmm, actually you can *always* use SPACE, even if it occurred in `s`,
just ensure the first call tacks on a `" 0"` suffix to get things started,
and maybe strip it at the end if necessary.

Alternatively, rather than a single String you might choose to pass around a
[Map.Entry(s, n)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V))
pair, which is how standard java offers Pair.of(s, n) from Apache Commons.
Take care to nicely format the string at the end when recursion is done.

---

This codebase is buggy and does not achieve its design goals.

Given the peculiar representation of an integer, and the lack of a test suite,
I would not be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: Thanks! The natural log was a problem. I found out, that i have to solve `floor(x*2+log_10(x)+1)` for x, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+floor%28x*2%2Blog_10%28x%29%2B1%29+for+x). In simply words: This allows me to reconstruct how many times it was doubled.